# SQL query running as local user instead of user in connection string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have a WPF application that accesses a SQL server using `SqlConnection` with a connection string.

```
private string connString =
        "user id=*****;" +
        "password=*****;" +
        "server=1.1.1.1;" +
        "Trusted_Connection = yes;" +
        "database=****;" +
        "connection timeout = 30";
private SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

The string contains the username and password for the account I want the program to use to access the database.  This works as I would expect it to on my machine.  Once I run it on another machine I get a an error:

> "Login failed for user 'Domain\local user'"

I am sure that I am just missing some sort of setting or configuration.

Any help would be great

Comment: Can you post the connection string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Trusted_Connection = yes` tells SQL Server to use Integrated (Windows) Authentication.  Your user name and password are ignored.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Gall dang that took me two days of Google to no avail.  Thank you so much!